# Client side stops sending data?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I'm trying to send mock data from client to server and connects perfectly using UDP. I stimulate a pack loss about every 3 sends. The problem with this if i uncomment the recv part it will just stop after sending once only! idk why at all. I included the code for both sides and commented out the recv part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int len, n;
    while(1){

        n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,
            0, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
            &len);
        printf("Client : %s\n", buffer);
        bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
            0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
            len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "PING";
    char *pocketLoss = "Pocket Loss";
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr;
    int worked = 0;
    int notWorked = 0;
    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int n, len;
    int counter = 0;
    while(1){
        if(counter%3 != 0){
            sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
                0, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                sizeof(servaddr));
            sleep(2);
            worked = worked + 1;
        }else{
            sendto(sockfd, (const char *)pocketLoss, strlen(pocketLoss),
                0, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                sizeof(servaddr));
            sleep(2);
            notWorked = notWorked + 1;
        }
        counter = counter + 1;
        printf("STTTILL");
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, MAXLINE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }

    printf("%d %d\n",worked,notWorked);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The messages you're receiving are not null-terminated, you can't print them with `%s`.

Comment: You should do `buffer[n] = 0;` to add the null terminator before printing.

Comment: `INADDR_ANY` can't be used as a destination address with `sendto()`. It's only for binding a socket, to indicate that you want to bind to all the local addresses.

Comment: If you want to send to the local machine, use 127.0.0.1 as the destination address.

Comment: No, you should use `printf("Server : %.*s\n", n, buffer)` to print them. You can't rely on `n` leaving room for a trailing null. @Barmar

Comment: I don't see any commented-out `recv()` here, or indeed any `recv()` at all.

Comment: @user207421 If `MAXLINE` leaves room for the null, it should work. He's just sending short strings while `MAXLINE` is 1024.

Comment: And I don't see how sending a datagram constitutes simulating a packet loss, and there is no such thing as 'connect perfectly using UDP'. It is easiest to do all your `printfs()` the same way @Barmar, then you can never be wrong.